# Add JavaScript documentation Sencha Architect

Tags: documentation, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

Is it possible to add documentation (not just comments) to your javascript methods in Sencha Architect. I cannot seem to add lines above methods because of the specific method views in Architect.

I am talking about the following documentation:

```
/**
* this documentation
*/
bla: function() { 
//I do know how to add this comment!

}
```

UPDATE:
Seems that it is not possible :(
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?281079-Sencha-Architect-Code-Documentation-%28JSDocs%

I will keep this thread open to see if someone knows a workaround to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Architect 3.1 or 3.1.1 will add commenting.  It's done in prototype form but we are racing to add Ext JS 5 so it's on the back burner until then.